# Why Integrate does not work in the first call?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, trigonometry

Consider an example (calculated in Mathematica 11.0.1.0):

```
In[1]:= Integrate[(Sin[(\[Pi] xc)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] xc)/Lc])/xc^2,{xc,x0,Lc+x0},Assumptions->{x0,Lc,xc}\[Element]Reals\[And]And@@(#>0&/@{x0,Lc,xc})\[And]m\[Element]Integers\[And]m>=0]
Out[1]= Integrate[(Sin[(\[Pi] xc)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] xc)/Lc])/xc^2,{xc,x0,Lc+x0},Assumptions->(x0|Lc|xc)\[Element]Reals&&x0>0&&Lc>0&&xc>0&&m\[Element]Integers&&m>=0]
In[2]:= Integrate[(Sin[(\[Pi] xc)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] xc)/Lc])/xc^2,{xc,x0,Lc+x0},Assumptions->{x0,Lc,xc}\[Element]Reals\[And]And@@(#>0&/@{x0,Lc,xc})\[And]m\[Element]Integers\[And]m>=0]
Out[2]= (1/(4 Lc x0 (Lc+x0)))(4 Lc^2 Sin[(\[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] x0)/Lc]+4 Lc x0 Sin[(\[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] x0)/Lc]-4 Lc x0 Cos[(\[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)] Sin[(m \[Pi] (Lc+x0))/Lc]-(-1+2 m) \[Pi] x0 (Lc+x0) SinIntegral[((1-2 m) \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)]-(1+2 m) \[Pi] x0 (Lc+x0) SinIntegral[((1+2 m) \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)]+Lc \[Pi] x0 SinIntegral[((1+2 m) \[Pi] (Lc+x0))/(2 Lc)]+2 Lc m \[Pi] x0 SinIntegral[((1+2 m) \[Pi] (Lc+x0))/(2 Lc)]+\[Pi] x0^2 SinIntegral[((1+2 m) \[Pi] (Lc+x0))/(2 Lc)]+2 m \[Pi] x0^2 SinIntegral[((1+2 m) \[Pi] (Lc+x0))/(2 Lc)]-Lc \[Pi] x0 SinIntegral[(Lc \[Pi]-2 Lc m \[Pi]+\[Pi] x0-2 m \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)]+2 Lc m \[Pi] x0 SinIntegral[(Lc \[Pi]-2 Lc m \[Pi]+\[Pi] x0-2 m \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)]-\[Pi] x0^2 SinIntegral[(Lc \[Pi]-2 Lc m \[Pi]+\[Pi] x0-2 m \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)]+2 m \[Pi] x0^2 SinIntegral[(Lc \[Pi]-2 Lc m \[Pi]+\[Pi] x0-2 m \[Pi] x0)/(2 Lc)])
```

As you can see, integration does not produce result at first call, but it does produce a valid result at second call. Why does it happen? Do I always have to call `Integrate` twice?

Comment: I do get a result the first time, also M11.0.1.  My guess (which may be completely wrong) is that `Integrate` attempts one method, but it times out (reaches internal time limits) before it can arrive at a result. During the course of this attempt, some partial results get cached. Thus the second time it is going to run faster, and will not time out. This would also explain why I do get a result and you don't: perhaps my computer is slightly faster.

Comment: These time limits are discussed e.g. [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5832/definiteintegration.pdf).  I tried your integral on a Raspberry Pi computer (M11.0.1), which is very slow, and I did not get a result either the first time or the second time.

Comment: 11.1 on Manjaro linux with an i5 which ain't the big kid on the block but quick enough, only takes a few seconds with the first try.